# my entire CSS dies in ie7 mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

It's bizarre.

This site works perfectly in all browsers but IE7. In ie7 NOTHING works. Most of the css just doesn't even render. IE8? Fine. Ie9 Perfect. Firefox and Chrome, of course.

Want to hear something weirder? this is a template site i have worked with before. Other sites built on essentially the same template DO work in ie7.

This is why i think whatever it is is simple.

I don't want to paste the code here - it's massive. But i'll give you a link to the site and to the css
site: http://canadianrecovery.ca 
css http://canadianrecovery.ca/css/screen.css

Thing is, i have document standard set to ie9  It works fine in ie7 mode with doc standards set to ie9

But i have noticed that most IE browsers don't display default doc standards... this is obviously some sort of issue with IE itself. But it's frustrating.. most end users have no clue how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

ella

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have found the reason. In your body-style (line 13), you have the following:

```
font-family: "Times New Roman;
```

See that unclosed quote? Seems like Chrome, FF, IE9 etc can fix that error, whereas earlier versions of IE read the rest of the CSS as your font-family declaration.

Comment: Also, to add to this, you should have a fallback. True almost every computer should have Times New Roman, but you should add `"Times New Roman", serif;` as best practices & a fall back just in case.

Comment: it's possible! Damn thanks. I didn't even see this.. And i fixed it. However I actually found a script (ie7.js) that you can include if you're running ie7. And it just fixed everything.

Comment: actually damn! This fixed a few more small issues that I was dealing with.. THANK YOU FRIEND!

Comment: neat! Remember to check the checkmark under the answer if you think it answered your question satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), it makes a lot of things possible in older/less compatible browsers without a lot of trouble. Try the development version to see if it can help you and compose your own production version targeting your specific needs to minimize the size (and speed) of the javascript library.

> Modernizr is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features in the user’s browser.

Comment: Thanks everyone. 

I actually found a solution. Look for a js script called ie7.js and include it with conditional comments.. it solves a LOT of ie7 issues.

Comment: Still the uncompressed development version of Modernizr is only 42kb against the ie7.js of 117kb while Modernizr fixes a lot more browser incompatibility issues. Compare the lists: http://modernizr.com/download/ vs http://ie7-js.googlecode.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I actually found a solution. Look for a js script called ie7.js and include it with conditional comments.. it solves a LOT of ie7 issues